# Python Solving Complex Coupled ODEs

Tags: python, scipy, physics, ode

I am attempting to solve a set of coupled ODEs that are complex valued, and then plot the results. I know what the plot should look like, a sin(x)^2 and a cos(x)^2 function. However, I am definitely not getting that. Just horizontal lines at 1 and 0 (my initial conditions). This is a numerical solution to the Radial Wave Approximation for an ammonia maser. I attempted to use complex_ode, but that keeps throwing argument errors, and I couldn't find any other helpful resource. Any help is appreciated.

```
    from scipy.integrate import odeint, complex_ode


## numerical solution from e  NON-RWA
def odes1(x, t):

    A = x[0]
    B = x[1]

    dgp_dt = (1/1j)*0.5 * B* (np.exp(-1j * t * (2*100)))
    dgm_dt = (1/1j)*0.5 * A * (np.exp(1j * t * (2*100)))

    return [dgp_dt, dgm_dt]

# intitial conditions

t0 = [0, 1]

# array of time values
k = np.linspace(0, 3*np.pi, 1000)


#solving the ODEs
sol1 = complex_ode(odes1, t0, k)

#plotting the solutions
plt.plot(k, np.real(sol1[:, 0]), label = r'$\gamma_{+}$'" No RWA", color = 'blue')
plt.plot(k, np.real(sol1[:, 1]), label = r'$\gamma_{-}$'" No RWA", color = 'red')
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("Time ("r'$\frac{1}{\Omega_{0}}$'")")
plt.ylabel("Population")
plt.show()
```

I know what the plot should look like, a sin(x)^2 and a cos(x)^2 function. However, I am definitely not getting that. Just horizontal lines at 1 and 0 (my initial conditions). The code attempts to plot the real parts, but I have also attempted to just plot as is, and it seems like python just cast the complex values to real.

Comment: Using the `solve_ivp` interface and its stepper classes should work seamlessly with complex ODE. You might have to insure that the initial values have type complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `complex_ode` interface, you are responsible for the integration. You also have swapped `x` and `t` in the method signature.

Lets rewrite your problem without scaling:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import integrate

def system(t, x):  # Mind the order of parameters
    return np.array([        
        (1 / 1j) * 0.5 * x[1] * np.exp(-1j * t),
        (1 / 1j) * 0.5 * x[0] * np.exp(+1j * t)
    ])
```

Your initial setup is:

```
x0 = [0, 1]
t = np.linspace(0, 3 * np.pi, 1000)
```

We define the solver:

```
solver = integrate.complex_ode(system) \
                  .set_integrator('vode', method='bdf') \
                  .set_initial_value(x0, 0)
```

Now we need to perform the integration by ourselves:

```
x = []
dt = t[1] - t[0]
while solver.successful() and solver.t < t.max() + dt:
    solver.integrate(solver.t + dt)
    x.append(solver.y)
x = np.array(x)
```

Finally we can visually check the result:

```
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(t, np.real(x))
axe.plot(t, np.imag(x))
axe.set_title("Complex ODE System")
axe.set_xlabel("Time, $t$")
axe.set_ylabel("Solution components, $y$")
axe.legend([
    r"$\mathcal{Re}\{y_0\}$", r"$\mathcal{Re}\{y_1\}$",
    r"$\mathcal{Im}\{y_0\}$", r"$\mathcal{Im}\{y_1\}$"
])
axe.grid()
```

[image]

Now if we perform the same operation on your scaled system:

```
def system(t, x):
    return np.array([        
        (1 / 1j) * 0.5 * x[1] * np.exp(-1j * t * 200),
        (1 / 1j) * 0.5 * x[0] * np.exp(+1j * t * 200)
    ])

x0 = [0, 1]
t = np.linspace(0, 0.25 * np.pi, 1000)
```

You still have oscillations but they are barely visible when plotting all solution at once:

[image]
[image]
[image]

But we can confirm they are still there